Is there a way to restrict people adding WhatsApp Business Phone number into group chats?
I am integrating WhatsApp Cloud API into my chat application. During the process, I've already integrated it, but I want to restrict people to add WhatsApp Business phone number into Group Chats.
It is possible to update the settings through WhatsApp itself, in order to use WhatsApp Cloud API, that number must not be registered as WhatsApp account. Therefore I can't edit through WhatsApp.
I know, I have to edit this via Business Portfolio, but I couldn't find it. I did multiple research, didn't find anything useful.
If somebody know, how to achieve this, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

WhatsApp Cloud API Phone numbers, already doesn't support joining groups or receive calls.
So even if you want to join a group chat within your WhatsApp Cloud API Phone number you simply can't.
